# I m not getting correct output for pre and post order

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, tree-traversal

// in this code I first created nodes stored them in a que and keep on removing them as I entered their left and right children. To make a node have no further children I entered -1 while entering data. Here I am not able to understand what is wrong with my code , I am getting wrong output for preorder and postorder traversals. It would be really great if you guys could help me out.

I made a class que for queue ds and inherited it in tree class in protected mode.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <math.h>
    using namespace std;
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        struct node *left;
        struct node *right;
    };
    class que
    {
    protected:
        int start;
        int end;
        struct node **arr;
        int n;
    
    public:
        que(int x)
        {
            n = x;
            arr = new struct node *[n];
            start = -1;
            end = -1;
        }
        void isfull()
        {
            if (end == n)
                cout << "Queue is full !!!" << endl;
            return;
        }
        int isempty()
        {
            if (start == end)
            {
                start = -1;
                end = -1;
                cout << "Queue is empty !!!" << endl;
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        void enqu(struct node *x)
        {
            if (end == n)
            {
                cout << "called" << endl;
                isfull();
                return;
            }
            end++;
            arr[end] = x;
        }
        struct node *dequ(void)
        {
            struct node *q = 0;
            if (start == end)
            {
                isempty();
                return q;
            }
            start++;
            cout << "Element removed is ->" << arr[start] << endl;
            return arr[start];
        }
    };
    class tree : protected que
    {
    
    public:
        struct node *head;
        struct node *ptr;
        tree(int n) : que(n)
        {
            head = 0;
            ptr = 0;
            enter();
        }
        void create(void)
        {
            ptr = new struct node;
            ptr->left = 0;
            ptr->right = 0;
        }
        void enter(void)
        {
            struct node *p;
            if (head == 0)
            {
                create();
                cout << "Enter root element of tree -> ";
                cin >> ptr->data;
                head = ptr;
                cout << "Enquing ptr - " << ptr << endl;
                enqu(ptr);
            }
            while (!isempty())
            {
                p = dequ();
                cout << "Enter left child ->";
                int x;
                cin >> x;
                if (x != -1)
                {
                    create();
                    p->left = ptr;
                    ptr->data = x;
                    cout << "Enquing ptr - " << ptr << endl;
                    enqu(ptr);
                }
                cout << "Enter right child ->";
                cin >> x;
                if (x != -1)
                {
                    create();
                    p->right = ptr;
                    ptr->data = x;
                    cout << "Enquing ptr - " << ptr << endl;
                    enqu(ptr);
                }
            }
        }
        void inorder(struct node *yes)
        {
            if (yes != 0)
            {
                inorder(yes->left);
                cout << "--> " << yes->data << endl;
                inorder(yes->right);
            }
        }
        void preorder(struct node *yes)
        {
            if (yes != 0)
            {
                cout << "--> " << yes->data << endl;
                inorder(yes->left);
                inorder(yes->right);
            }
        }
        void postorder(struct node *yes)
        {
            if (yes != 0)
            {
                inorder(yes->left);
                inorder(yes->right);
                cout << "--> " << yes->data << endl;
            }
        }
        int count(struct node *yes)
        {
    
            static int x = 0, y = 0;
            if (yes == 0)
                return 0;
            x = count(yes->left);
            y = count(yes->right);
            return x + y + 1;
        }
        int height(struct node *yes)
        {
            static int a = 0, b = 0;
            if (yes == 0)
                return 0;
            a = count(yes->left);
            b = count(yes->right);
            if (a > b)
                return a + 1;
            else
                return b + 1;
        }
    };
    int main()
    {
        int x;
        cout << "Enter height of tree - ";
        cin >> x;
        int max = 0;
        max = pow(2, x + 1) - 1;
        tree tr(max);
        cout << "Preorder traversal -- " << endl;
        tr.preorder(tr.head);
        cout << "Inorder traversal -- " << endl;
        tr.inorder(tr.head);
        cout << "Postorder traversal -- " << endl;
        tr.postorder(tr.head);
        cout << "\n No. of elements -- " << tr.count(tr.head);
        cout << "\n Height of tree --" << tr.height(tr.head);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to reduce the code to reproduce your problem, see [mre]  and also please elaborate more what you intended to do, what you expected output exactly is and what you got instead. While still maintaining a code snippet we can compile and execute.

Comment: Just a note: It seems some C-isms have snuck into your code. 1) `#include <cmath>` not `math.h`. 2) `new node` - not `new struct node`. 3) Functions not taking an argument does not need to have their argument as `(void)` - just make it empty.

Comment: A class constructor should be small and simple, and only initialize members variables to a  known state. It shouldn't really go on to ask for user input. Rather you should separate construction and input.

Comment: I suspect that a little bit of copy-and-paste programming has been involved in your traversal functions.

Comment: Try to use the `count` and `height` functions more than once, and find more bugs. (Why did you make the local variables `static`?)

Comment: BTW: `pow` is no good in integer contexts.

Answer (score 0):

The `preorder` and `postorder` functions doesn't call themselves recursively. Instead they call the `inorder` function, which will lead to all but the root will be printed using `inorder`.

Comment: oh thats so stupid of me, thank you so much :)